# @requestparam value = date spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/reservations")
public class ReservationController {
    private static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    @Autowired
    private ReservationService reservationService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getReservation(@RequestParam(value="date", required=false) String dateString, Model model){
        Date date = null;
        if(dateString != null){
            try {
                date = DATE_FORMAT.parse(dateString);
            } catch (ParseException pe) {
                date = new Date();
            }
        }else{
            date = new Date();
        }
        List<RoomReservation> roomReservationList = this.reservationService.getRoomReservationsForDate(date);
        model.addAttribute("roomReservations", roomReservationList);
        return "reservations";
    }
}
```

I understand that the @RequestParam annotation is used to bind parameter values of query string to the controller method parameters. So for example, http://localhost:8080/reservations?date=2017-01-01. However, where does the value="date" come from? I dont see any value "date" inside my html page.

Answer (score 0):

if you submit a form as method:"GET" (not POST) and form contains a input field named date then submitting this form will hit this handler method.

Comment: I checked the html form, it contains a datepicker input like <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker" area-describedby="basic-addon1" />. Does this line implicitly have a value="date"?

Comment: <input  name ="date" type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker" area-describedby="basic-addon1"  />                                        just add name="date" attribute inside input tag.that's all